# How to remove pre-selection in PrimeNg dropdown

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using `p-dropdown` from `PrimeNg 15`. It's a very simple dropdown.

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="myReactiveForm">
  ...
  <b>Dropdown:</b>
  <p-dropdown
    [options]="colors"
    optionLabel="name"
    formControlName="color" // <-----------Form control variable
  ></p-dropdown>
  ...
</form>
```

**TS:**

```
colors = [
    { name: 'black', code: 'blk' },
    ...
];

constructor() {
    this.myReactiveForm = new FormGroup({
      ...
      color: new FormControl(), // <----- kept this contructor blank
      ...
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.clearForm();
}

clearForm() {
    this.myReactiveForm.controls.color.setValue(null);
}
```

Still I can see the first item i.e 'black' is selected in the dropdown. Please pitch in. Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-znheib).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind `[autoDisplayFirst]` to the `p-dropdown`

```
   <p-dropdown
    [options]="colors"
    optionLabel="name"
    [autoDisplayFirst]="false"
    formControlName="color"
  ></p-dropdown>
```

The docs says about the option:

> Whether to display the first item as the label if no placeholder is
> defined and value is null.

Comment: `optionValue` is still causing the problem. It is not allowing me to set the value through setValue(). Can I remove it?

Comment: sounds like you checked my old answer, just updated it, no `optionValue` needed